# Проблема с cookies на android в google chrome

Tags: php, android, ajax, google-chrome, cookie

Здравствуйте.
Есть интересный, крайне непонятный баг.
Обнаружил, что на сайтах с авторизацией, когда данные храним в куках, на некоторых устройствах в браузере google chrome на андроиде данные в куки не пишутся. Важный момент, что запись происходит через ajax-запрос к php-скрипту.
Выяснилось, что баг проявляется не на всех андроидах.
Решение нашли - подключить ssl-сертификат, по https все везде работает.
Может кто-то сталкивался с такой проблемой?
Из-за чего так происходит?

Comment: Вопрос актуален... Не могу тоже понять избирательность Андроид Хрома? Некоторые сайты без HTTPS мы едим, а некоторые отказываемся подчистую жевать... При этом все остальные браузеры на этом же устройстве спокойно воспринимают всё...